# How should this (erroneous) HTML5 be parsed? Where should the end tag be inserted?

Tags: html, html-parsing

I have a test HTML5 file that includes the content:

```
<body>
  <video autoplay="" id="remote" width="240"/>
  <script>
    ...
  </script>
</body>
```

The rules say that the "/" in the `video` tag is incorrect and the parser should ignore it, so we are left with a `video` start tag with no matching end tag.

As far as I can see, `Chrome`, `Safari`, and `JSoup` all close the `video` element before the `script` element, whereas `validator.nu` and `AngleSharp` close it after the `script` element. Which is correct, and where is the relevant rule in the HTML5 specification?

Correction: I was misreading the browser results. `Chrome` and `Safari` do indeed wrap the script element inside the video element. It's only `JSoup` that does something different, which gives me confidence that the others are all getting it right.

Comment: What @sideshowbarker said. Also, not even `</body>` will pop `video` off the stack of open elements, only change the insertion mode that changes where comments are inserted, but anything else, including whitespace, is inserted into the `video` element. See http://software.hixie.ch/utilities/js/live-dom-viewer/saved/11155

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct behavior per-spec is that the `video` element remains open and the `script` element becomes its child. Any implementation doing otherwise is non-conformant with the spec requirements; specifically, there’s nothing in the spec which, when the `<script>` start tag is seen, requires popping that `video` element of the stack of open elements, nor for [generating an implied end tag](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#generate-implied-end-tags) for it.

In fact, there’s nothing in the spec that would *ever* cause a `video` element without an end tag to be popped off the stack of open elements — nor for an implied end tag for a `video` element to ever be generated. (Or in the [words of a comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74978033/how-should-this-erroneous-html5-be-parsed-where-should-the-end-tag-be-inserte?noredirect=1#comment132373092_74978033), *“not even a `</body>` [end tag] will pop `video` off the stack of open elements”*.)

The relevant spec section for this is the [The "in body" insertion mode](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#parsing-main-inbody) part of the parsing algoroithm, in the *“A start tag whose tag name is one of: "base", "basefont", "bgsound", "link", "meta", "noframes", "script", "style", "template", "title"”* step — which says: do as for the [The "in head" insertion mode](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#parsing-main-inhead), in the *“A start tag whose tag name is "script"”* step.

And the *“appropriate place for inserting a node”* (referenced in that step) is right where that `<script>` start tag is in document order, because no “foster-parenting” is needed (it’s not table content).